# How to access multiple <p> tags one at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="test_id">
    <p>Some words.</p>
    <p>Some more words.</p>
    <p>Even more words.</p>
</div>
```

If I parse the HTML using:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://my_url"))
```

and run

```
doc.css('#test_id').text
```

in the console I get:

```
=> "Some words.\nSome more words.\nEven more words"
```

How do I get the first `<p>` element only?

---

I think I figured it out with `.children`

```
doc.css('#test_id').children[0].text
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using `text` on the right type of object.

If you're looking at a [NodeSet](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#text-instance_method) the `text` documentation says:

> Get the inner text of all contained Node objects

If you're looking at a [Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#text-instance_method) AKA Element, it says:

> Returns the content for this Node

Here's the difference:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div id="test_id">
    <p>Some words.</p>
    <p>Some more words.</p>
    <p>Even more words.</p>
</div>
EOT

doc.search('p').class  # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
doc.search('p').text  # => "Some words.Some more words.Even more words."

doc.at('p').class  # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
doc.at('p').text  # => "Some words."
```

`at` is like `search(...).first`.

Typically, if we want the text of a NodeSet we'd use:

```
doc.search('p').map(&:text)  # => ["Some words.", "Some more words.", "Even more words."]
```

which makes it easy to pick the text of a specific node.

See "[How to avoid joining all text from Nodes when scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594656/how-to-avoid-joining-all-text-from-nodes-when-scraping)" also.

> `doc.css('#test_id').children[0].text`

Well, yeah, you can do that, but `children` isn't going to do the same thing:

```
doc.search('#test_id').children
# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc31580ca24 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc315103714 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc31580d5a0 "Some words.">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc315107f44 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc3151036ec name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc315107cc4 "Some more words.">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc315107b20 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc3151036c4 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc3151078a0 "Even more words.">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc3151076fc "\n">]
doc.search('#test_id').children[0] # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc31580ca24 "\n    ">
doc.search('#test_id').children[1] # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc315103714 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc31580d5a0 "Some words.">]>
```

versus:

```
doc.search('#test_id p')
# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc315103714 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc31580d5a0 "Some words.">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc3151036ec name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc315107cc4 "Some more words.">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc3151036c4 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc3151078a0 "Even more words.">]>]
doc.search('#test_id p')[0] # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc315103714 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc31580d5a0 "Some words.">]>
doc.search('#test_id p')[1] # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fc3151036ec name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fc315107cc4 "Some more words.">]>
```

Notice how `children` is returning the text nodes between the tags used to format the HTML. You have to be aware that `children` returns *everything* in the HTML below the selected tag. This is useful sometimes but for general text retrieval it's probably not what you want.

Instead, use the more selective `'#test_id p'` selector and iterate over the returned NodeSet and you'll avoid the formatting text nodes and won't have to account for them when using a slice or index into the NodeSet.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
$("p:first-child").text();
```

This will give you all the first children of ANY parent element. So for your example it should work