# Render HTML to stdout as formatted text using Ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

While building a CLI Google Card viewer, I stumbled on the problem of *rendering* HTML in command line like the browsers **w3m** or **lynx**. The closest I have come is using the *text* spit out from Nokogiri:

`Nokogiri::HTML::parse(card_snippet).text`

But it prints out as follows:

```
"Albert EinsteinTheoretical PhysicistAlbert Einstein was a German-born theoretical physicist. He developed the general theory of relativity, one of the two pillars of modern physics. Einstein's work is also known for its influence on the philosophy of science. WikipediaBorn: March 14, 1879, Ulm, GermanyDied: April 18, 1955, Princeton, New Jersey, United StatesInfluenced: Satyendra Nath Bose, Wolfgang Pauli, Leo Szilard, moreInfluenced by: Isaac Newton, Mahatma Gandhi, moreBooksThe World as I See It1949Relativity: The Special a...1916Ideas and Opinions2000Out of My Later Years2006The Meaning of Relativity1922The Evolution of Physics1938People also search forIsaac NewtonEduard EinsteinSonStephen HawkingElsa EinsteinSpouseMileva MarićFormer spouseThomas Edison"
```

But using lynx:

`cat card_snippet.html | lyx -dump -stdin`

```
Albert Einstein
Theoretical Physicist
Albert Einstein was a German-born theoretical physicist. He
developed the general theory of relativity, one of the two pillars
of modern physics. Einstein's work is also known for its influence
on the philosophy of science. Wikipedia
Born: March 14, 1879, Ulm, Germany
Died: April 18, 1955, Princeton, New Jersey, United States
Influenced: Satyendra Nath Bose, Wolfgang Pauli, Leo
Szilard,
```

Note: After stripping off some noise. But nonetheless the line endings are proper.

Any ideas for a similar solution in Ruby? The html snippet: [Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/pYKwACBp).

Comment: Your question is not a good fit as worded. You're basically asking us to recommend something, or give our opinions on how to write something but it'd result in a tutorial. Instead, on SO you're supposed to identify what you want to do, try writing it, then when you run into a problem ask a specific question about that problem. Please read "[mcve]" also; The data (HTML) needs to be in the question itself, using the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Links rot then break, resulting in questions that don't make sense.

Comment: The problem you're seeing is due to using `text` on a NodeSet. You need to iterate over all the elements and extract their text individually, which will then make more sense.

Comment: Would it suffixe to capture the w3m output by running a system ckmmand in ruby?

Comment: @maxpleaner thats possible, but I was wondering if I can do away with such a dependencies.

Comment: @theTinMan okay will take care next time. Thanks for the suggestion about Nodeset.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40917450/128421 for more information on using `text` on Nodes vs. NodeSets.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,

```
require 'nokogiri'
html = `curl http://pastebin.com/raw/pYKwACBp`
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
puts doc.text.gsub(/[\r\n]+/,"\n").strip
```